# Trouble populating text field widget while executing node.create through Service using Rest server

Tags: 7, nodes, services

I have a Rest server running using the Services module which is setup to receive node and user requests.  I have also created a new content type with the following fields:

[image]

I am able to add new instances of this content type using Poster (a Firefox plugin for creating http-post requests) using an http-post to my rest server with the following body (using application/json content-type):

```
{
  "title":"online submission",
  "type":"basic_content",
  "field_text":[
    {
      "value":"Some Text"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried many different variations of this json string (including make it all one line) and it never seems populate the text field.  Could anyone shed any light on this?  I am willing to use a different content-type if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field values need to be surrounded by an array, which holds all the potentially multiple entries for the field, and yet another array which holds all of the potential translations for the field.

In PHP that looks something like this:

```
$node->field_text['und'][0]['value'] = 'Some Text';
```

I haven't tested it but I'd guess the JSON equivalent would be something like this:

```
"field_text":
{
  "und": 
  [
    { "value": "Some Text" }
  ]
}
```

That may need a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I'll play around with this.  Where does the "und" come from?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say: it stands for "Undefined language". You can also access it through the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE`.

Comment: Okay sweet I think I'm starting to understand, thanks again!  It worked!